# How to make components rendered via {{component}} helper independent

Tags: ember.js, components, ember-octane

I have few instances of component (let's call it `<Row />`) with given template:

```
    {{component @resultComponentName result=@result}}
```

I'm calling `<Row />` component from `<Terminal />` component like this:

```
{{#each @rows as |row|}}
  <Row @result={{row.result}} @confirm={{fn this.confirm}} @resultComponentName={{this.resultComponentName}}/>
{{/each}}
```

`<Terminal />` component has property:

```
@tracked resultComponentName;
```

which is handled in action `confirm()` in `<Terminal />` component:

```
if (cmd.resultComponentName) {
  this.resultComponentName = cmd.resultComponentName;
} else {
  this.resultComponentName = 'result-component';
}
```

where `cmd` is some Ember Model with property:

```
  @tracked resultComponentName = 'other-result';
```

now I want to change `@resultComponentName` in only one instance but when I am changing  `@resultComponentName` all of the component `<Row />` instances re-render.

How can I prevent that behavior and make every instance independent?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: thats not how it should behave, how do you change it, and how do you call `<Row />`?

Comment: @Lux I did edit my question. Hope it is more precise now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `@tracked resultComponentName;` exists in your `Terminal` component, and so only once for the entire list.

Now I'm not sure how your `@rows` is related to `cmd` here, because thats the interesting question. If each row is a `cmd` you could just do this:

```
<Row @result={{row.result}} @confirm={{fn this.confirm}} @resultComponentName={{row.resultComponentName}}/>
```

If its different it totally depends how you want to map for which rows you want which `resultComponentName` and where you want to store that information. You maybe even want to move that login into the `Row` component itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I assume that my architecture is a bit weird. I have `TerminalRow` as a component and as a Model as well. I moved `resultComponentName` to a `TerminalRow` Model and it works now exactly as I wanted. Thanks!